# Mirth: Use Condition to store date from hl7 message

Tags: mirth

I have three different table for blood pressure, Blood Sugar and Heart rate.
I want to filter data received and store to respective tables. I looked into many sites am not able to find the process. Could anyone please help me....

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. "Data received" what data, is it HL7v2, is it CDA, is it your own proprietary format? Do you have a problem parsing your incoming whatever data or the problem is with putting SQL query to the destination scrip?

Comment: The data received is HL7, i need to insert received data into respective table. My problem is how to identify which table the received data to be inserted. At one time i receive only one type of data.

Comment: Well, basically you take HL7 spec, check for each segment and field (assuming you are receiving HL7v2 messages), then take your database structure and map tables and fields to received data. How do you want anyone to answer your question if we know nothing about your message type (ADT, ORU, SRM, etc.) and database you use (e.g., PracticeFusion, openEMR)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAPI APIs to parse HL7 messages. Then extract and store required data in database based on the Segments from where the information is coming.

[HAPI API Link](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/)

Check if it helps.

Comment: In Mirth messages are already parsed (using HAPI under the hood) and each field can be referenced using E4X notation.